# Unable to build Azure IOT SDKs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, linux, azure, raspberry-pi2, azure-iot-sdk

I've just followed [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/) when I tried to build the updated sample solution by entering the following:

```
cd ~/azure-iot-sdks/

sudo ~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/setup.sh   

chmod +x ~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/build.sh

~/azure-iot-sdks/c/build_all/linux/build.sh
```

I got the error shown in the following screenshots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6iUN.png

I can't find anything to fix this. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Please make sure that the titles to your questions are about your question. No *please help me* stuff. The point of SO is to help.

Comment: I'm always having trouble building the sdk using raspberry pi, have you tried  cross-compiling? https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that it fails to find the "main" entry point, which is defined in azure-iot-sdks\c\serializer\samples\simplesample_http\linux\main.c file in the http sample.

Two things you can check on,

1. Make sure you're using gcc >= 4.9 and cmake >= 3.0, I see you're correctly referencing gcc, also check on your cmake version via `cmake --version` command. Follow this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install cmake 3.x.
2. When you pull the azure-iot-sdk repository, make sure you use the `recursive` keyword, or using `git submodule update --init --recursive` to make sure you pulled all the submodule codes.

I myself have found trouble building sdk using rapberry, due to limited memory resources, an alternative way you can also try is cross-compiling, you can find tutorial in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/c/doc/SDK_cross_compile_example.md).